# Laravel - How to categorize data by the 3rd table relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have a problem to categorize data by the third related table. lets asume i have simple table like bellow.

categories table

```
+----+---------+
| id |  name   |
+----+---------+
|  1 |  novel  |
|  2 |  comics |
+----+---------+
```

then the books table

```
+----+--------------+------------------+---------+
| id |  title       |    category_id   |  price  |
+----+--------------+------------------+---------+
|  1 |  Don Quixote |     1            |   $10.  |
|  2 |  Naruto      |     2            |   $5.   | 
|  2 |  One Piece   |     2            |   $5.   |
+----+--------------+------------------+---------+
```

then the transactions table

```
+----+--------------+--------------+---------+
| id |     book_id  |    pcs       |  total  |
+----+--------------+--------------+---------+
|  1 |  1           |     3        |   $30.  |
|  2 |  1           |     2        |   $20.  |
|  2 |  2           |     2        |   $10.  |
|  2 |  3           |     2        |   $10.  |
+----+--------------+--------------+---------+
```

what im trying to achieve is categorize transaction data with based on category data.
in example: sum the transaction total payment of books categorized as novel.
so based on the above data i will get the **50$** as the result.

i have no idea what to do so please give me some reference how to solve this problem.
thankyou in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have write the relation between categories, books and categories, transactions you can simply write:

```
Category::first()->transactions;
```

for get all transactions for the first categories but you should create a hasManyThrough relation between categories, transactions

Comment: hasManyThrough at the category model right?

Comment: yes and hasMany in the book model

Comment: Oke let me try this solution